# Apache2 Options Indexes

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I am experimenting with Apache and Option Indexes. I mv index.html to no_filename. When I went to www.dunno.com I got a forbidden webpage instead of the directory listing that I was expecting. Why is this? I have mod_autoindex installed and enabled in httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Servername www.dunno.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/web1
<Directory "/var/www/web1">
Options Indexes  
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Options +Indexes
```

Make sure the underlying file system permissions allow the User/Group under which Apache is running to access the necessary folders/files.

Comment: Will list the directory contents of the parent web root or do I need a child directory in /var/www/web1 for it to transverse to? I was exepecting it to list all the files in /var/www/web1

Comment: Well you can leave /var/www/web1 as DocumentRoot, just make sure that apache, www-data, httpd whatever distro apache user/group has read/write permissions to /var/www and all the subdirectories.

Comment: It has access because before I had index.html it was able to read it and serve it. I moved index.html to noname file so it wouldn't be found and list other files.

Comment: Still not working? Are you sure that autoindexing module loaded?

Comment: Still not working...I have LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so in httpd.conf. Log shows: Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/web1/

Comment: Make sure you do not have any .htaccess file in /var/www/web1 or /var/www which has "Options -Indexes" or in httpd.conf

Comment: Also when you do "sudo apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES" does it list autoindex_module?

Comment: double checked but no luck.

Comment: Can you pastebin your httpd.conf? Or vhost config if you are using them.

Answer (score 0):

Is the directory readable?  You need to have "r" and "x" bits set on the directory (chmod 0555 or chmod a+rx) for the user to read the directory listing.

To verify:

1. Find out what user httpd runs as (it is different on different systems)
2. become that user: "sudo -u www bash" if the user is "www"
3. Make sure you can "cd" that directory and that "ls -l" works.

Comment: permissions are good, if i was able to serve index.html before then  i don't see a permissions issue.